# Search by ID label in an HTML with hxselect

Tags: html, bash, parsing

I am parsing an HTML file "index.html" in a bash script with hxselect. It may or not have the following ID on a tag, but if it has, I need to get the content.

Eg.

I have "someID" as the only information to search and the following HTML

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="someID" class="c">some other html stuff</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I need to get ONLY "some other html stuff" as result

I can't make it happen doing cat index.html | hxselect -c 'someID'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Match `id` attribute:

```
hxselect -c '#someID' < file.html
```

Match `class` attribute:

```
hxselect -c '.c' < file.html
```

Match `div` tag with path:

```
hxselect -c html body div < file.html
```

Match only `div`:

```
hxselect -c div < file.html
```

Output in all cases:

```
some other html stuff
```

---

See: `man hxselect`

Comment: If you get "End tag _tag1_ doesn't match start tag _tag2_" [try piping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51913432/scraping-information-within-html-tags-in-unix-with-curl-and-cut#comment118851239_51913624) through `hxclean` first

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend **`xmlstarlet`** tool for such cases:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//div[@id='someID']" -n index.html
```

The output:

```
some other html stuff
```

http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html#idm47077139652416

---

The same can be done with `xmllint` tool:

```
xmllint --html --xpath "//div[@id='someID']/text()" index.html
```