# Scraping information within HTML tags in unix with curl and cut

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed, cut

I'd like to figure out the ***simplest*** way to grab content between HTML/XML tags from a remote resource in unix. Here's how I thought it would work.

```
curl https://www.google.com | grep "<title>" | cut -d '<title>' -f2 | cut -d '</title>' -f1
```

So first I `curl` the resource, grep out the line with the tag I want (which sometimes means the whole HTML, because many websites are minified these days).

Then I cut out everything after the opening `<title>` and finally I cut out anything after the closing ''.

This causes an error though: `curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 8192)`.
The error seems to happen because `cut` does not support delimiters that are anything but a single character.

I liked how my approach was a very minimalist way to grab the data I wanted and am looking for another simple way to do it.

---

Additionally, even if it did work, my solution would only work for a single tag in the HTML. What about for a tag that appears many times?

Comment: This was doable with `sed -n`, but like others have stated, it's probably not a good idea to parse html as plain text. Just for reference the `sed` approach would look like: `curl https://xkcd.com/ | grep "<title>" | sed -n "/<title>/,/<\/title>/p"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This set of tools by W3 seem to fit your use case. http://www.w3.org/Tools/HTML-XML-utils/README

For something small enough you can get away with something like [this](https://www.joyofdata.de/blog/using-linux-shell-web-scraping/). (I'd use Python+lxml for anything else)

And remember: [You can't parse [X]HTML with regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1279003)

Comment: This is interesting, I'll check out `hxextract`, thank you. Although since this is essentially simple text manipulation, I feel like it should be easy to do with native unix utilities. Especially since I might want to use this on other non-html webformats like json or even plain text.

Comment: For json you should check [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/), awesome little tool.

Answer (score 0):

This would be probably easier in another lang like py or php but there is a great tool delivered by the package html-xml-utils (goes by other names as well .

Example (ec2 linux AMI) :

```
sudo rpm -ivh html-xml-utils-6.7-2.1.x86_64.rpm 
curl https://www.google.com | hxselect title
... ... ...
<title>Google</title>
```

More info:
    - https://www.w3.org/Tools/HTML-XML-utils/README

Comment: I'm having trouble using the library with some sample docs: they always seem to break the parsing engine. 

```
$curl https://www.google.com | hxselect title
End tag </head> doesn't match start tag <meta>
```

I've contacted the main maintainer to understand if there is a public repo for the library accepting contribs/issues.

Comment: @GuillaumeBerche so far I solved that issue piping through `hxclean` (also `hxnormalize -x`) before sending to `hxselect`